# In my Android app, Digits theme not working after upgrading digits (by Twitter's Fabric) to version 2.0.0

Tags: android, twitter-fabric, twitter-digits

### [Disclaimer: DEPRECATED - Digits has changed implementation and ownership. The question/answer is outdated]

I have been using Digits in my Android production app for few months now without any issues. Recently Digits was upgraded to version 2.0.0. I tried upgrading my implementation for the same by following [Digits upgrade guide](https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/upgrading.html). Everything is working as expected but theme.

> My implementation:

In my app, in the activity which extends `Application`, I have initialized digits [as given in docs](https://docs.fabric.io/android/digits/theming.html#), and post that used the following code to set theme:

`new Digits.Builder().withTheme(R.style.CustomDigitsTheme).build();`

where `CustomDigitsTheme` is:

```
<style name="CustomDigitsTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_primary</item>
        <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/text_hint</item>
        <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="dgts__accentColor">@color/accent</item>
        <item name="dgts__logoDrawable">@drawable/logo</item>
</style>
```

Note that Digits provide another way to set theme (using `DigitsAuthButton`). But I can't use it because in my implementation I'm using regular `Button`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Disclaimer: DEPRECATED - Digits has changed implementation and ownership. The question/answer is outdated]

Solved.

Silly to put this code:

`new Digits.Builder().withTheme(R.style.CustomDigitsTheme).build();`

instead of:

`Fabric.with(this, new TwitterCore(twitterAuthConfig), new Digits.Builder().withTheme(R.style.CustomDigitsTheme).build());`